# Eclipse WebLogic exploded deployment republish only JSP on file change

Tags: eclipse, deployment, weblogic

I'm using Eclipse with WebLogic extensions.

I'm developing my J2EE application as Exploded. Each time I modify a JSP file content it is copied automatically inside the exploded deployment folder.

Unfortunately this scenario works only for JSP files, any other project file, like CSS and JS, must be copied by hand.

Is it possible to tell Eclipse to auto deploy other file types too?

Thanks!

Comment: There should be an option in Eclipse when publishing to Weblogic like: Eclipse server view, select open in the popup menu, and in the top right corner title Publishing, select the radio button "Automatically publish when resources change" Is that already selected?

Comment: Yes, it is selected, but as I described it publishes only changes to JSP and not for other file types. Do you know why? Thank you!